# Wordpress Media Upload error

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problems with uploading large images to WordPress 3.5 I get the following error:

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

- I've checked the permissions on the upload folder and they are correct (even tried setting them to 777)
- I've tried disabling all plugins , switching back to a default theme and adding various lines of code to the .htaccess folder.
- I've also tried the suggestions [in this article](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-25-image-upload-error-wordpress-fix/).

If I try  to upload the files locally it works, if I try it on a different server it works. Can anyone tell me what might be causing this? It only happens on files with large file sizes.

Comment: have you checked the `upload_max_filesize` etc. that required for large file upload in your server's `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the hosting providor we used and how there server was setup. We moved to a different hosting providor and all worked as expected.

Comment: i founded the exact problem in function.php. After removing style tag in my file. it works fine. then how to i dynamically change images?

Answer (score 0):

Check Your function.php file(rename it) and than check its working.then you have problem in function.php i solved my problem through this may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check php.ini values

`echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize') ;
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
echo ini_get('memory_limit');`

if its values are less then below then use below code to increase values

`ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '128M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '128M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the upload_file_maxsize and max_execution_time values in PHP.INI Builder. Also you could also try disabling "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)" in media settings. http://debug.ga/wordpress-media-upload-errors-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved in editing php.ini on server. It comes to problems with large images. Check the upload_max_filesize etc. As said jogesh_pi.